# Instruction that makes Desktop Screen persist after boot sequence in Linux

Tags: linux, boot

I only want to know the C/++ statement that makes Desktop Screen persist after boot sequence in Linux is complete. All the peripheral should work and the CPU should be able to service a routine.

EDIT:
The Desktop: icons, date, time, text, wall-paper, task-bar, start-button do not come by themselves. There has to be a function call or some construct that makes them appear on the screen in Linux. I want to know what this function or construct is.

Thanks.

Comment: I really didn't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: How do I put something on a desktop screen and make the visual persist? What is the role of RAM and other system resources to put a visual on screen? I am trying to know the mechanism which can put something on desktop screen. For instance: to run a program, the program should be loaded from HDD to RAM, then the RAM talks to the CPU to complete the task. Along the same line, what RAM or other system resources does to put a visual on the desktop screen? I think, instead of knowing the instruction that does something, I should know the mechanism first.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong than you are probably interested in **making your OS**.

If you want the `C/C++ code` of the Linux Kernel then it is available [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux).

You should also have a look at

`http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page`

`http://forum.osdev.org/`

You will find many hobbyist there doing same thing. You can also start with **Assembly Langauge** to print simple Text on screen.